# Method not returning string value c# <List>

Tags: c#, list

```
public List<string>  Test_IsDataLoaded()
    {
        try
        {
            if (GRIDTest.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                int countvalue = GRIDTest.Rows.Count;
                GRIDTest.Rows[0].WaitForControlReady();

                List<string> ReleaseIDList = new List<string>();

                int nCellCount = GRIDTest.Cells.Count;

                for(int nCount = 0;nCount<nCellCount ;nCount++)
                  {
                        if(nCount %5==0)
                        ReleaseIDList.Add((GRIDTest.Cells[0].GetProperty("Value").ToString()));
                  }
                return ReleaseIDList;    
             }

        }
        catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Method throws me error = Not all code path return a value. Whats wrong in code.

Comment: The clues in the text, you should ask yourself do all you code paths return a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because if an exception occurs or the if statement returns false, there will be no return statement executed.

Add a default  return statement in the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks all, closing the thread now. Thanks for valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is:

> Not all code path return a value

Which is correct. You only return a value inside an `if` statement:

```
if (GRIDTest.Rows.Count != 0)
```

What if `GRIDTest.Rows.Count==0`. Then you won't return a value.

---

As a fail-safe (In case your code errors, or your if statement isn't true), you can add the following to the last line of your method:

```
return new List<string>();
```

This will ensure that if no other returns are made, then an empty `List` will be returned

Answer (score 0):

You add `return`  in the end of your method

```
public List<string>  Test_IsDataLoaded()
    {
        try
        {
            if (GRIDTest.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                int countvalue = GRIDTest.Rows.Count;
                GRIDTest.Rows[0].WaitForControlReady();

                List<string> ReleaseIDList = new List<string>();

                int nCellCount = GRIDTest.Cells.Count;

                for(int nCount = 0;nCount<nCellCount ;nCount++)
                  {
                        if(nCount %5==0)
                        ReleaseIDList.Add((GRIDTest.Cells[0].GetProperty("Value").ToString()));
                  }
                return ReleaseIDList;    
             }

        }
        catch (Exception)
    {
    }

return new List<string>() ;//<-------here
}
```

Comment: Perfect.Thanks Aghilas, let me compile once

Comment: I'am happy to help you Santii20

Comment: Thanks, there was a problem in my code ReleaseIDList.Add((GRIDTest.Cells[0].GetProperty("Value").ToString, instead of Cells[0], it should be Cells[ncount]

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind complaining above problem is that you are not returning the value from all over the method....It only returns from `if condition` but if it skip `if statement`, there'll be no returning value.So you've to be sure about returning value all over the method....

You can do like this:

```
public List<string>  Test_IsDataLoaded()
{
   List<string> ReleaseIDList = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        if (GRIDTest.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int countvalue = GRIDTest.Rows.Count;
            GRIDTest.Rows[0].WaitForControlReady();
            int nCellCount = GRIDTest.Cells.Count;

            for(int nCount = 0;nCount<nCellCount ;nCount++)
              {
                    if(nCount %5==0)
                    ReleaseIDList.Add((GRIDTest.Cells[0].GetProperty("Value").ToString()));
              }

         }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return ReleaseIDList;  
}
```